# Iteration of resultset in schema method of kendo mvc grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using kendo MVC grid with custom binding of datasource. I want to do some preprocess to resultset data in client side javascript before binding the data to grid. But I dont know how to do the iteration of resultset in schema method of kendo custom binding. Anyone please tell me how to iterate the data in schema method.
My Code:

```
 .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Custom()
            .Type("aspnetmvc-ajax")
            .Transport(transport => transport
            .Read(new
            {
                url = Url.Action("Action", "Controller"),
                beforeSend = new Kendo.Mvc.ClientHandlerDescriptor
                {
                    HandlerName = "beforeSend"
                }
            })
             )
            .Schema(schema => schema
                .Data("Data")
                .Total("Total")
                .Errors("Errors")
            )
)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Schema's "parse" function to parse the server response: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-schema.parse

I can't speak directly to how to do this using the MVC approach, but in pure javascript you could do this to convert a property called StartDate to a Date object (for example)

```js
var mydataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  transport: {
      read: function(e) {
        
        var data = GetData(); //do something to get data
        e.success(data);
        }
    },
  schema: {
            parse: function (response) {  
                $.each(response, function (i, item) { 
                    if (item.StartDate && typeof item.StartDate === "string") {
                        item.StartDate = kendo.parseDate(item.StartDate);
                    }
                });
                return response;
            }
        }
  }
});
```